# table item group (grp_id,grp_name,grp_desc).& 2 table item (item_id,grp_id,name,disc) form 2nd column need a combo box where it will convert to id

Tags: c#, combobox, insert

Here is the code for my ComboBox

```
   string my_querry = "select * from [Item Group]";
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                grpname.Items.Add(reader["item_grp_name"].ToString());

            }
```

Now I need an ID

```
OleDbCommand command= new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection=conn;
command.CommandText="select item_grp_id from [item Group] where item_grp_name='"+ grpname.Text +"'" ;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if(reader.Read())
                MessageBox.Show("found the result");
```

How do I retrieve the Id from the `OleDbDataReader`? Is it something like this:
`int id=OleDbDataReader.GetData;`?

Comment: did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
int id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
//do other stuff
}
```

or I could be completely misunderstanding your question, it was worded a little confusingly

Comment: I made a combo box from first table by showing only string values but how can i use its corresponding grp_id which is to be inserted in the second table.(item_id,grp_id,name,desc)2nd column name.